# Array Modifier Start/End Cap is Off

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

I am experiencing the following problem and can't seem to figure out the reason or solution to it.

I want to add an object as a start and end cap to the array modifier. However the results are not what I wished for - I do not want a space between the start/end caps and the middle object.

I made sure to apply scale properties to the mesh (strg + a -> Scale).

What am I not considering or aware of?

[image]

### Edit:

The origin of the obj. to use for the caps is at the obj.'s geometry (origins to geometry), see:

[image]

Appreciate the help in advance guys!

Aldin

Comment: Check the origins of the object used for cap.

Comment: Georges, I have edited my original post and added the information. Can't seem to figure it out still :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array modifier sets the distance in between instances according to the given input that you assign, this applies to start/end caps, so unless the start and end caps have the same thickness on the array axis (in your case the Y axis) there will be a gap or they will overlay with the Array object, I found 2 solutions to this:

#### First solution:

1- Make a copy of the start/end object so that you have two copies using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> so you can use one of them for the start cap and the other for the end cap
2- Enter the start cap object's Edit mode using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all using <kbd>A</kbd> then move the mesh on the axis used for Array, in your case it's the Y axis, press <kbd>G</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> and move your cursor, in your case the origin should be outside the mesh, think of it this way, the distance in between the origin of the start object and the surface touching the Array object, should be the same width of the Array object on Y axis.
3- Do the same for the End object, except that the direction of the movement should be reversed.
[image: Start cap origin]
Notice the origin in the image above.
Keep in mind that if you assign the Start or End cap before moving the origin of their objects, you will need to re-assign after editing, the Array modifier will not update automatically.

#### Second solution:

You can use two Array modifiers, one of them to repeat the Array object on the Y axis, without using the Start/End cap object.
Then use the second modifier only for the cap object, so the repeat in the second modifier should be Count:1, then select the cap and end object and use the input in Relative or Constant or both, to set the distance input.
This way you are assigning separate input for the array itself (using the first array) and for the the Start/End cap (using the second array).
You will still need to move the origin of the Start/End cap object, but you don't have to make separate copies for the Start cap and the End cap.

Hope this was helpful, happy blending!

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 1):

That's just the way this modifier works. You will have to model a Cap object that has the same dimensions as your Object where you add your Array Modifier to. The modifier isn't aware of different dimensions of your cap object but simply extends your object one more time like the Array Modifier would do but replaces this last instance with the Cap object.

So you have to provide a Cap object that would fit in place as if the Array Modifier would have an increased Count and should place a further copy of your original object.

So instead of scaling your Start Cap cube like let's say at 0.2 in x direction with your Pivot Point set to Individual Origins, you should position your 3D cursor right at your cubes face in positive x direction and use it as your Pivot Point for scaling. You'd have to create a different (or duplicated and -1*x-scaled) End Cap object as well.

Comment: hey, thank you for the explanation about the array modifier and a solution!

Comment: des basst scho ;-) schön, dass jemand sich bedankt und eine hilfreiche Antwort positiv bewertet - weiter so

Answer (score 1):

I have read all the previous explanations and I think they are good, I also think a few visual aides might be helpful, since I had a little trouble visualizing what distance between which origin and whatnot.

[image: Array Modifier Start and End Cap Spacing and Pivot Point Requirements]